# Oracle Coherence from Node.js

Tags: oracle-coherence

All,
We are trying to reuse oracle coherence from our node.js app. From Oracle client documentation, clients are available for c++,java and .net. i donot see for node.js specifically. Any inputs would be greatly appreciated. I see that we can have cache exposed via Rest APIs with Coherence Rest API, is that widely used?

Comment: Update: We eventually resorted to using a dedicated proxy node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use REST client, see
[Oracle documentation with example](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHCG/rest_example.htm#COHCG5231) .

generally it means that you'll have to start a dedicated Proxy Node(s) with additional configurations see [Deployment Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHCG/rest_deploy.htm#COHCG5262)  clear.

We used Grizzly as web server in production.
off course it will be slower than native tcp client, so you'll need to make some performance tests.